# Coordinates for my Javascript game - based on an angle, when do I use Sin Cos and Tan?

Tags: javascript, math, html, canvas

JavaScript coordinates Sin, Cos or Tan?
I am trying to learn some basic trigonometry for game development in the web browser. I know the soh cah toa rule etc. I know we are also working between -1 and 1.

I am confused though, I need to work out x and y coordinates separately depending on an angle.

Here is what I have to work out the direction of my angle in x and y, which does work (Thanks to Loktar).

```
velY = -Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
velX = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
```

What I understand from this is I am finding the cos of x and y based on a small formula to convert my angle variable to radians.

But, why does cos need to be used for x and sin for y? Where does tan come into this? Is this to do with the 4 quadrants of a circle?

How do I know when to use sin cos or tan when I am only given an angle and I need to work out where on a circle that angle places using x,y?

Any simple diagrams or explanations would be extremely helpful!

Thanks

Comment: Looks to me you are doing some kind of rotation (maybe I'm wrong ;)). Might be worth reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: I am working out the angle of my object and the path it must travel on. That Wiki page seems like the stuff I am doing, it's just quite full on haha, I'll try to make some sense of it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basic Definitions (from your trigonometry book):

```
cos ϴ = x/h, sin ϴ = y/h
```

Gratuitous ASCII art to describe x,y,and H :

```
         _
         /\  assume we're going this way 
        /
       /|
      / |
  h  /  |
    /   |  Y
   /    |
  /ϴ    |
 +-------
    X
```

A vector can be split into a sum of two vectors. (you can think of this in the diagram as going northeast for H meters is the same as going east for X meters and north for Y meters)

H in this case corresponds to your current thrust. You want to find the X and Y components of that thrust.

since   cos ϴ = X / H  (basic definition of cosine),  we can say (via simple algebra)

```
X = H * cos ϴ
```

however, ϴ is assumed to be a radian measure. if you're using degrees, you have to multiply by Math.PI / 180 to get the correct value. hence, you have

```
ϴ = angle * Math.PI / 180
```

We're very close! Now our classic definition-of-cosine formula (when translated to our terms) looks like

```
cos (angle * Math.PI / 180) = X / H
```

H being our Thrust vector, X being only the horizontal part of our thrust vector.

"Now, wait a minute," you say. "why am I using cosine to calculate the *vertical* velocity then? Your axes seem flipped to me." Ah, yes. This is standard geometric orientation -- angles are measured as a counter-clockwise rotation from `-------->` directly to the right. Your axes are flipped because you are storing your angle as a "clock-angle", i.e. 0 degrees is at 12:00. In order to use the standard geometric equation, we have to mirror our entire universe so that the X and Y axes are flipped. Luckily, the mathematical way to do this is simply to switch all your X's and Y's around in the equations.

```
standard 'math' coordinate system
            _
             /\  
            /
           /|
          / |       angles increase counterclockwise
      h  /  |
        /   |  Y
       /    |
      /ϴ    |
     +----------- (zero degrees starts here)
  (0,0)  X       


your coordinate system

  (zero degrees starts here)
       ^
       |   angles increase clockwise
       |   /
       |  /
       |ϴ/
       |/
       +
```

Finally, why is there a negative in the cosine? Because here is the cartesian system where we do our math in

```
 ^ y-axis
 |
 |
 +----> x-axis
```

here is the cartesian system that you are drawing to (probably a canvas)

```
+------> x-axis
|
|
v y-axis
```

since the y-axis is facing the other direction, you multiply all y-values by a negative 1 to get the correct orientation

Comment: That's an excellent explanation! I'm just trying to get my head around the first example. I thought that the cos=x/h because that would be the adjacent/hypotenuse? Also, is there a reason the first diagram is to the left and the bottom 2 are to the right? Would this work the same if the triangle was moved in to your second diagram? This has really helped... I have made a simple diagram of my understanding, is this correct? http://img576.imageshack.us/i/55330174.jpg/

Comment: you are correct, cos should be x/h. let me fix it before I confuse anyone :)

Comment: *Sits with sense of achievement*. Great! I love this stuff. So any quadrant of the circle can be used to figure this stuff out. I should have listened more at school I think. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, added the fix, and a diagram to explain why your velY's are based on cosine rather than sine. Your diagram accurately describes the *definitions* of sin and cosine, but as you can see from my terrible terrible ASCII art, the coordinate system you use for your game is not actually the same coordinate system your diagram is in.

Comment: I think your ASCII diagrams are epic. Thanks for the explanation!