# Calculate a path from one object to another and move along it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Let's say I have an object like this...

```
var objA = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    speed:{x:0, y:0},
    angle:0,
    turnSpeed:8
}
```

...and I each "step" in a game I want to move it towards objB, which is at coordinates (10, 10). ObjA is already moving and suddenly needs to move to objB's position. Let's say objA has a function `turnTo()` which can turn it towards objB each step based on its `turnSpeed`. I could do something like...

```
objA.speed.x += Math.cos((90 - obj.angle) * Math.PI / 180);
objA.speed.y += -Math.sin((90 - obj.angle) * Math.PI / 180);
```

...to move objA towards objB based on the angle, but if objA is already moving, it is unlikely to ever hit objB because this doesn't take into account objA's current speed.

How can I calculate a path to objB so that objA will hit it precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take a look at [Coordinates for my Javascript game - based on an angle, when do I use Sin Cos and Tan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027950/coordinates-for-my-javascript-game-based-on-an-angle-when-do-i-use-sin-cos-an)

You know the x and y coordinates of objB (I assume they remain constant) and you can get the x and y coordinates of objA using JavaScript, thus you can solve the problem as a triangle from any point objA is to objB using simple trig.

Comment: Right, but that alone won't get objA to objB if objA is already moving. You can kind of see what happens in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQgGV/1/).

Comment: This can give you the angle needed and the distance for objA to collide with objB.

Comment: Ok, using the angle and distance how would you approach it?

Comment: I would stop objA when turnTo() is called just long enough to calculate the angle required for it to hit objB, then resume its moving.

Comment: So I guess what I'm really asking is how to calculate that required angle. I understand the trig, but I'm not sure how to compensate for the speed and I don't see how stopping the object temporarily will help as it has to maintain that velocity after. I'll make a new question as this is getting a bit lengthy.